# How can I make my bot make embeds from collected messages

Tags: discord.js

I want to make my bot to collect messages and then put them in to a embed

I already tried collectmessages and awaitmessages but it's not working.

```
const colectoraddbuilding = await new  Discord.MessageCollector(msgobject.channel, msg => msg.author ==  msgobject.author ,{time: 10000});

building1 = ${colectoraddbuilding.collected};
```

there are not errors but when i try to send the embed where the building 1 var is is then its not adding the new text to the building 1 var

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are a few problems with your code that show a lack of understanding of some JavaScript concepts. You may want to read up more before tackling message collectors and rich embeds, by checking out the links I have provided below.

Your `await` operator would require an asynchronous context, which you can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

However, for the goal you want to achieve, you could avoid async-await altogether and instead attach an event listener to the [`end` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=e-end) emitted by your `MessageCollector` instance, using Node.js' [`EventEmitter.on`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) method. You can find a helpful guide about collecting messages [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors).

Your template literal isn't valid either. For starters, it should be wrapped in backticks (`` ` ``). You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Once you have successfully collected messages, you can follow [this guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=rich%20embeds%20discord&rlz=1C1CHBF_enSG772SG772&oq=rich%20embeds%20discord&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1992j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to try your hand at rich embeds.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the messages and that part is working, then I think the problem is here:

```js
building1 = ${colectoraddbuilding.collected};
```

Two things, first, you should use `const` in you declaration of building1 to prevent unwanted globals, and two, `building1` is not a string, so that could be a big problem.

Final:

```js
const building1 = `${colectoraddbuilding.collected}`;
```